# Action Controller Live for different user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, redis, ruby-on-rails-4

Im experementing with the new Rails 4 feature ActionControllerLive.
I try to build up a system with many users who are notified when somebody clicks a specific link for example enters `messages#index` controller.

**My problem** is that at the time all users are notified when somebody uses `messages#index` controller even the user who entered the controller!

**Im searching** for a solution so that i can only inform specific users!

In all my controlles i have `@current_user` but i dont really know how i should avoid that he also gets a notifcation about what he is actually doing!

**One possible solution** would be that i sort the notifications with jquery at the frontend but this also would mean that you can spyout notifications that are privat.

**Another solution** is that every user has its on channel but i dont know i this really makes sens and how i should transpose it!

Here is my actual code: Thanks!

```
def events
  response.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/event-stream"
  redis = Redis.new
  redis.subscribe('gaga') do |on|
    on.message do |event, data|
      response.stream.write("data: #{data }\n\n")
    end
  end
rescue IOError
  logger.info "Stream closed"
ensure
  response.stream.close
end



  def index
   @message = Message.new
   @departments = Department.all.where.not(id: @current_department.id).last(4)
    $redis = Redis.new
    data = {"user" => @current_user.name}
    $redis.publish "gaga", data.merge('msg' => "#{@current_user.name} entered messages index").to_json
     end
```

And forntend:

```
source = new EventSource('/formular')
source.addEventListener 'gaga', (e) ->
  alert e
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had this problem :)

We solved it by using a [private channel](http://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_private_channels)

---

The ActionController::Live component doesn't know who is listening to whatever it sends, so the best way to keep your code efficient is to send to private channels which are dependent on the user

Here's an example from our live code. It uses [Pusher](http://www.pusherapp.com), which is websockets, but is the same principle:

```
  #app/controllers/controller.rb
  Pusher['private-user-' + current_user.id.to_s].trigger('my_event', {
     message: "Removed"
  })

  #app/assets/javascripts/javascript.js
  channel = pusher.subscribe("private-user-#{gon.user_id}")
  channel.bind "my_event", (data) ->
      alert data.message
```